# Analyzing HTTP traffic

Tags: http, http-headers, packet-sniffer, useragent, packet-analyzer

I am trying to solve the problem for a while and i couldn't find a proper answer online. I have a file with mobile traffic (from an Android device) and I am trying to check whether an http request is sent from the browser or from a mobile app (for example, Ebay app and their mobile site). Unfortunately, checking the host or the user_agent fields on http headers didn't yield any result (they are exactly the same, the host contains the address `m.example.com` and the user_agent contained general information about the device - something like: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; SAMSUNG SM-T550 Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/3.2 Chrome/Safari/537.36`).
Does anyone have an idea what can I do to check it ?

Thank you !

Comment: What difference does it make to you if the traffic comes from an app or the phone's browser? I'm asking, not because I doubt the validity of your question, but I'm wondering what actual problem you are trying to solve if you knew the answer.

Comment: It is actually part of my academic assignment, it is for statistic analysis of users' using habits

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It is not homework, it is part of my academic research

Comment: Regardless, it's not about managing systems in a professional environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no way to definitively determine the type of device network traffic comes from. User agents can be trivially changed.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably get 70-90% of the way there just by pulling client IP addresses from your webserver's access logs and doing a DNS lookup on them, then grouping them by domain. Most web log analyzers do this as part of their traffic analysis.

If you need a more complete solution, and are willing to work for it, there's interesting research on browser fingerprinting that uses page-embedded javascript to extract details on the browser, its plugins, and the device it runs on. But it would require a fair bit of work to implement this.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your answer!
I am not sure I understand your advise, how can I do a DNS lookup on clients IP ? Or maybe I miss understood you and you ment that in most cases there are separete servers for mobile apps and browsers ?
In case I am willing to "work hard" for it, where can i read about the research you mentioned ?

Comment: How, exactly is a RDNS lookup going to tell you what kind of device is making the query?

Comment: The question, at least as I read it, was not about detecting devices, but determining if the "http request is sent from the browser or from a mobile app" via a company such as eBay. If it's the latter, I'd expect the http request to come from a server owned, or at least operated by, eBay. Maybe the OP can clarify (OP?).

Comment: Correct, I have no interest in the device information, I only want to know if the user used the mobile application or the browser (I gave ebay just as an example, I want to check it for any other service during the experiment period).
By the way, I am not trying to build some kind of security mechanism, so if you have a solution that work in the typical cases it is also good (cheating users doesn't interest me very much ;) )